# C# FTP Download - JSON File

Tags: c#, json, ftp

In my code I want to upload and download a specific JSON-File to a FTP-Server.

The serializing works great and also the upload. When i look up the file via - for example - FileZilla, the content of the file is correct. (on the server)

But when i download this file with my application (and with my code - NOT with FileZilla), I don't get any exceptions, but the file is nearly empty. This is the only content:

> {}

And here is my code for downloading:

```
        string ResponseDescription = "";
        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + "ftp.strato.com" + "/" + verzeichnis + "/" + file.Name);
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.benutzer, this.passwort);
        req.UseBinary = true;
        req.UsePassive = false;
        req.Proxy = null;
        try
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(destinationFolder + @"/" + destinationFile.Name, FileMode.Create);
            int ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (ReadCount > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
                ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            ResponseDescription = response.StatusDescription;
            fs.Close();
            stream.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message); // TODO - better Errorhandling
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger to see what's going on? Also, you're setting `req.UseBinary` to `true` but the file is a text file, I don't know if that could be an issue or not.

Comment: Hi, yeah i stepped through the code. I cant see a problem. And yeah ... this was a try. Of course this is not a binary file and the property should be "false". It dont work with "true" and "false". This was only a "try". :)

Comment: @MaxLebold a) your code seems to be correct b) the file you get (`{}`) doesn't looks like a partially downloaded file, instead a valid empty json. Your bug should be somewhere else.

Comment: But what or where can it be? When the upload to the server works great, the file on the server is correct and only after downloading the file with my code, the file is empty.

Comment: Please post your answer **as an answer** below, and then mark it accepted. You shouldn't edit answers into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was my mistake. The problem wasnt the download - the code was correct (as you said).

After downloading the file the JSON-Deserialization runs and here was the cause. I had a little mistake in my deserialization-logic.